# how to marshal object and return as a view (and not as JSP page) in spring + xstream

Tags: spring-mvc, marshalling, xstream

I'm trying to follow this tutorial and build a RESTful service that can un/marshal an object to/from XML.
http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=54

The marshaller of choice in the article is xStream (I found it to be very easy to use and configure).

The point is, using STS -- Spring's own flavor of Eclipse bundled with tcServer -- I built a project based on the STS template of MVC. This is a legacy project started from Spring version 2.4, and I migrated it to version 3.0. So, the template created all the necessary XML markup, and I added my configuration to point the view to the correct object conversion (to the xstream marshaler).

Here is part of my bean that sends the object to a new view (copied out from the link):

```
<bean id="bookXmlView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">  
     <constructor-arg>  
         <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">  
             <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/>  
         </bean>  
     </constructor-arg>  
</bean>
```

It all worked nicely until I installed the latest STS version 2.5.2.RELEASE and created a new MVC project from a template. (The new template does not use urlrewrite.xml anymore, among some other changes).

I set the correct configuration 1 by 1 as the tutorial suggests, but now no matter what, the view is always directed to a JSP, so if my controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authors/{authorId}")  
public ModelAndView getAuthorById(@PathVariable String authorId) {  
    Author author = bookService.getAuthorById(authorId);  
    ModelAndView mav =new ModelAndView("bookXmlView", BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX+"author", author);  
    return mav;  
}
```

It would always try to return to a author.jsp view and not the object as XML. I tried many things with no success. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

---

**UPDATE -------------------** 
As noted I added logs:

I set it as DEBUG level and discovered something:

> **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
>   **DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'bookXmlView': no URL paths identified**

---

Notice this line:  Rejected bean name 'bookXmlView': no URL paths identified.
Searching this indicated maybe a clash between  `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and my autodetectAnnotations in the xstream settings?

Any case, after invoking the link, I got the following log entry. Notice it forwards the view to /WEB-INF/views/bookXmlView.jsp:

> **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for [/test/page_init]
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapping [/page_init] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [test.test.test.HomeController@a087de] and 2 interceptors
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/test/page_init] is: -1
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker - Invoking request handler method: public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView test.test.test.HomeController.getObject()
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'bookXmlView'
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name **'bookXmlView'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/xmlView.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'**
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.books' of type [test.test.test.ObjectTest] to request in view with name 'bookXmlView'
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/xmlView.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'bookXmlView'
>   **DEBUG**: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request

Comment: What do your logs say?  Try turning your log levels to ALL or DEBUG so that you can see all the output.  The problem will likely be found in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it at last!
First I tried a different marshaller - JAXB2 but xstream should work as well.

Next thing is the definition - turns out for some reason the configuration uses this (wrong):

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

using only **InternalResourceViewResolver**

while definition for **org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver** is ignored. The solution for that is to define them both in one bean called **ContentNegotiatingViewResolver** as follows:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                    </bean>
            </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
        <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.mycompany.dashboard.Person" />
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

<bean name="person" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <constructor-arg ref="marshaller" />
</bean>
```

That configuration solved my problems and person object I played with was not directed to a JSP view but marshaller turn is to an XML:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addPerson() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setAddress("address 123");
    person.setAge(50);
    person.setName("Andrew");
    System.out.println("new person: " + person);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("person",BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "person",person);
    return mav;
```

Hope it would help others in the future too.

Comment: JAXB is the best choice: http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html